# Refactoring a (simple) statement

Tags: c#, refactoring

I want to refactor a method but I'm not too sure how to but I know you can do it.

My current method:

```
public bool AdminShutdown(int accountID, int accountPin)
        {
            var status = false;
            if (accountID == AdminLogin && accountPin == AdminPin)
            {
                status = true;
            }

            return status;
        }
```

I think it should be something like
`var status = (accountID == AdminLogin) && (accountPin == AdminPin)` but that doesn't work (    `Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'`).

Suggestions?

P.S. Would this code work?

```
var tempReturnPerson = AccountHoldersList.Single((x => x.AccountNumber == accountId));
```

instead of:

```
public AccountHolders ReturnAccountInfo(int accountId)
        {
            //use linq to do this later
            var returnPerson = new AccountHolders();
            foreach (var person in AccountHoldersList)
            {
                if (accountId == person.AccountNumber)
                {
                    returnPerson = person;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return returnPerson;
        }
```

Comment: What are the types for `AdminLogin` and `AdminPin`?

Comment: That error message doesn't make any sense.  Did you initially type `=` instead of `==` somewhere in your `if` block?

Comment: Ad PS - better would be SingleOrDefault(...) because it returns null if the predicate isn't matched

Comment: @amnezjak rather FirstOrDefault with a new element if return is null. There's no idea of "single" in the method to rewrite.

Comment: Bit of topic but, you might want to look into your class naming. Does the class AccountHolders contain multiple accounts? If not it should be named AccountHolder. That said, "Holder" does not convey anything meaningful therefore I would call the class Account. Same with AccountHoldersList, you don't need the type name in your variable name. Just name it Accounts (or accounts). For similar reasons I would rename ReturnAccountInfo() to GetAccount(). Last but not least, identifying admin by user id seems like not a very bright idea. I would rather have an enum for that and add it to Account class

Comment: Pro tip: get Resharper it will convert for loop to LINQ for you and overall it's great tool for refactoring

Comment: @RytisI It does not, thanks for the tip I'll rename it to AccountHolder. I personally prefer AccountHolder as I click faster to the name AccountHolder rather than Account so I'll leave it as AccountHolder despite you being correct. Adding in list is just my own personal thing, I am aware I can quickly check what type it is but if I type in list my lists come up and it's less effort to check. I prefer GetAccountInfo although GetAccount is good too. I don't know what you mean by enum for it please explain :). This method is a lazy one, if I can dedicate more of my time I'll get rid of it. Thanks

Comment: @RytisI Are you kidding :O?! I have Resharper, how do I convert code into code that uses LINQ with it?

Comment: @user3245390 have a look here http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Loop+can+be+converted+into+a+LINQ+expression

Comment: @user3245390 by enum I mean you could have an something like this: http://pastebin.com/xNCjE9RH

edit: moved to pastebin, comments don't format that well

Comment: @RytisI Ah, I see what you mean now thanks

Comment: @user3245390 about the type suffix on the variable, it is considered a bad practice among most developers. The reasons for that are the following: what will happen if you change type of AccountList to LinkedList or a HashSet? Will you rename the variable? Even if so, what about other developers? Are you sure they will rename the variable? Even if the variable gets renamed it might cause hundreds of line changes, which is not great. Even worse if the variable is not renamed then you've got a variable of type HashSet that's named AccountList. That might be bit confusing and cause bugs to occur.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if AdminLogin and AdminPin are int, than

```
public bool AdminShutdown(int accountID, int accountPin)
{
    return (accountID == AdminLogin && accountPin == AdminPin);
}
```

The error message you get make me think you may have used an `=` instead of an `==`

**EDIT**

For your second question

```
var tempReturnPerson = AccountHoldersList.Single((x => x.AccountNumber == accountId));
```

should rather be

```
var tempReturnPerson = AccountHoldersList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AccountNumber == accountId) ?? new AccountHolders();
```

If you want the same result as your method.

Comment: Thank you :). I'll accept your answer when it lets me

Answer (score 0):

"(accountID == AdminLogin && accountPin == AdminPin)" can simply be evaluated to a bool

```
public bool AdminShutdown(int accountID, int accountPin)
{
    return (accountID == AdminLogin && accountPin == AdminPin)
}
```